# SolrJ - How to add a blocked document without child documents

Tags: solr, solrj

Nested documents is quite useful to model structural hierarchy data.

Sometimes, we only have parent document which doesn't have child documents yet, we want to add it first, and then later update it: re-add the whole document including the parent documents and its all child documents.

But we found out that in the server, there would be two parent documents with same id: one without child document, the other one which contains child documents.

http://localhost:8983/solr/thecollection_shard1_replica2/select?q=id:*&fl=*,[docid]&distrib=false

```
<result name="response" numFound="3" start="0">
<doc>
  <str name="docType">parent</str>
  <str name="id">9816c0f3-f3ae-4a7c-a5fe-89a2c481467a</str>
  <int name="[docid]">0</int>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="docType">child</str>
  <str name="id">e27d2709-2dc0-439d-b017-4d95212bf05f</str>
  <arr name="_root_">
    <str>9816c0f3-f3ae-4a7c-a5fe-89a2c481467a</str>
  </arr>
  <int name="[docid]">1</int>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="docType">parent</str>
  <str name="id">9816c0f3-f3ae-4a7c-a5fe-89a2c481467a</str>
  <arr name="_root_">
    <str>9816c0f3-f3ae-4a7c-a5fe-89a2c481467a</str>
  </arr>
  <int name="[docid]">2</int>
</doc>
```

How I can avoid the duplicate parent documents? 
How could I add a blocked document without child documents?

- I can workaround this by deleting first before add new documents but the performance would suffer

Thanks a lot for your help and response.

Comment: Is your `id` field defined in as a uniqueKey?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, id is the uniqueKey.

Comment: Could you post the schema of this collection?